# Avoiding indentation in Python else and elif

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation, auto-indent

In writing a Python code in Wing or IDLE, inside the `if` condition, we must have an indentation for each line. But the `else` and the `elif` part must be aligned with `if`. However when I type `else:` or `elif:` in a newline, it has an indentation and I must remove it manually. I have seen it in several IDEs like Wing.

Is there any way to avoid indentation for `else` and `elif`? Indeed I need this:

```
if (condition):
    do this
else:
    do this
```

But when I type it, it's like:

```
if (condition)
    do this
    else:
    do this
```

Comment: What language/IDE are you talking about?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, In Python, I will edit it

Comment: Wouldn't this need to be a question about a specific IDE or editor, then?

Comment: This behavior is very specific to your IDE or Editor, perhaps you could try a different one, i use vim and it indents fine, perhaps you could try PyCharm? i hear good things

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In several IDEs I have this problem, in Wing and IDLE specifically

Comment: Then [edit] the question to ask (only!) about either Wing or IDLE.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wouldn't that make this a "general computing hardware and software question"?

Comment: @ayhan, programmers' editors are "software tools commonly used by programmers"; the general consensus is that they're inside the topic.

Comment: Hmmm...I never thought of this as an issue, but having an IDE actually be able to recognize an else, except, finally clause and unindent for you would be pretty convenient.  I wonder if I can fashion a custom conditional in Sublime...

Comment: Try using atom, it can recognize a whole bunch of syntax and adjust tabs accordingly

Comment: @AlanLeuthard you can. FWIW Sublime works with `if: ... else:` but not `if: ... elif:`.

Comment: @DavyM this question was not asking for editor suggestions. I feel this question is more asking, semantically, why this particular catch seems to fail on multiple IDEs and text editors where all other catches work fine.

Comment: Wow.  It's amazing what you learn even from bad questions: Sublime 3 unindents for all of these cases out of the box, even elif.  Strange I've never noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to believe the editor will somehow know how many lines the indented *suites* of code should have.

It would be easy to make editors "outdent" if those suites were all one line, but a cursory inspection of any moderately complex Python program will show that is clearly not the case.

Which means it's up to us to indicate the end by outdenting manually, usually with SHIFT-TAB, at the end of the clause.